# POSIX Spawn time-out error for static site on Github Pages

Tags: github, posix, github-pages

I have a static plain HTML/CSS website on Github pages without Jekyll.

Everything has been working just fine until recently the following build error started appearing:

```
The page build failed for the `master` branch with the following error:

POSIX::Spawn::TimeoutExceeded
```

I am not sure why this occurs, as my commits were mostly incremental changes to existing HTML files.

Googling the error message has not yielded anything useful. What could cause this problem and how can it be fixed and prevented in the future? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the exact same error 20 minutes before you posted this question, but it now appears to be working for me. I would check it again now - you'll need to create another commit and push to the repository for the build to happen again.

As for your other question - this is likely a problem on GitHub's (or more likely Jekyll's) end - nothing you did caused this.

Comment: I can confirm that this issue resolved itself after a while and appears to be a problem internal to GitHub. The solution is therefore to simply wait and re-commit.